# How to make a layout scale with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to use difference units (%, em, pt) to make a layout scale across different DPIs. I tried changing the Windows DPI settings, but in each scenario the layout looked like the same size eventhough the whole system looked bigger. How do I make the layout to scale up and down respecting the DPI?

For example,

```
<p style="font-size: 1em;">Testing out</p>
```

Will not scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calibrate the browser to match the DPI of the screen. Not all browsers will get it from the system DPI.

That said, don't. Most systems do not have their DPI correctly calibrated, so trying to do anything based on that is a waste of effort.

Comment: So, I just should not worry? I am not quite clear why would there be any use for say `em` over `px` if it does not actually scale. I know that older browsers like IEs have some problems, but I'm living in 2010 (IE9, Fx4, Chrome 10, Opera 11). Does it make any difference to use `em` over, say, `px` when it comes to resolution-independent scaling? I know that `em` is a relative unit and `px` is an absolute unit, but it seems that there is no difference in actual scaling.

Comment: `em` will scale relative to the font size (which should be set to a sane user preference unless you override it). There is nothing practical you can do to scale relative to the DPI.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate all your CSS from PHP, plus add a little JavaScript to calculate the user's DPI, which you can then use to scale pixel values.

This is how to do it:

```
<div id='testdiv' style='height: 1in; left: -100%; position: absolute; top: -100%; width: 1in;'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
dpi_x = document.getElementById('testdiv').offsetWidth;
dpi_y = document.getElementById('testdiv').offsetHeight;
</script>
```

(I took the code from [this useful page](http://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php))

All you need to do then is send these values to php and scale all css pixel values by either 96/dpi_x or 72/dpi_x, depending on what your inital designs are layed out for.

Comment: That won't work. It takes what the browser thinks is the DPI, uses that to draw an element, then measures the pixel size. Effectively it does: `((x * 72) / 72)`. You get the setting, not the real DPI. The browser will scale using that measurement if you just use `pt` or `in` in the first place, so it is a wasteful dependency on JavaScript. Just to underline the point, the URL you referenced claimed that 0.85" was 1" on my system.

Comment: Hm. Point taken.  You could, though, use the same method to scale by screenWidth or innerWidth - that way you would rely on the actual size of the view pane.  You could set a minimum value to prevent it from scaling below, say, 800x600, but enlarge everything if you have more pixels to work with.  You could also just set a default value, if JavaScript won't return anything, so the dependency would be minimal.